# Blender Minecraft torch black lines

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine

I was importing a Minecraft village model and I noticed black borders or lines on the torches. I couldn't remove it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a problem with alpha rendering. Under *Material Properties* ➝  *Settings*, are the materials set to "*Alpha Clip*"?

That will take you from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Eevee requires this extra step over Cycles.